# create breadcrumb from class

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, breadcrumbs

I have a title for example this:

```
<h1 xmlns:umi="umi" class="header" umi:element-id="34" umi:field-name="h1">Руководство</h1>
```

and I want to display the title on other div "submenu" like this:

```
var bread =  $(".header").text();
$('#submenu').html('<span style='color:#fff;position: absolute;margin-left: 15px;'>'  >  + bread + '</span>    ') ;
```

But seem this code doesnt work

Comment: And I want to display the title from class="header"

Answer (score 0):

Change your second line to:

```
$('#submenu').html('<span style="color:#fff;position: absolute;margin-left: 15px;">'+ bread + '</span>') ;
```

You had the wrong quotes on the inner part of your HTML, and extra `>`.